# Erro ao conectar cadastro formulário , com Banco de dados

Tags: java, html, jsp, netbeans, wildfly

Abaixo print do erro `Cannot invoke "String.trim()" because "in" is null`:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`Erro no Netbeans:Deployment error: Error during incremental deploy: java.io.IOException: C:/Terçou/wildfly-26.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/website.war
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 43 seconds).

```css
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
                //1)Receber os dados vindo do formulário CadastrarProdutos.html
                int codigo;
                String nome, marca;
                double preco;
                codigo = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("codigo"));
                nome = request.getParameter("nome");
                marca = request.getParameter("marca");
                preco = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("PRECO"));

                try {
                    //2)Conectar com o Banco de dados

                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bancoterca", "root", "1234");

                    //3)Enviar os dados para a tabela do banco de dados
                    PreparedStatement st = conexao.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO produtos VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
                    st.setInt(1, codigo);
                    st.setString(2, nome);
                    st.setString(3, marca);
                    st.setDouble(4, preco);
                    st.executeUpdate(); // executa o INSERT na tabela do BD
                    out.print("<p>Dados salvos com sucesso</p>");


                    //4)Desconectar do banco de dados
                      conexao.close();

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
                out.print("Você não colocou o driver JDBC no projeto " + x.getMessage());
            } catch (SQLException x) {
                if(x.getErrorCode()==1062){ //Tentativa de duplicação de chave primária (código)
                    out.print("Este código de produto já está cadastrado");
                }else{
                    out.println("Erro número:" + x.getErrorCode());
                    out.println("Entre em contato com o administrador do sistema");
                }
            }
        %>
    </body>    
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="CadastrarProduto.jsp">
            <p>
                <label for="codigo"> Código:* </label>
                <input type="text" name="codigo" size="20" maxlength="20" id="codigo" required>                
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="nome"> Nome do produto:* </label>
                <input type="text" name="nome" size="50" maxlength="50" id="nome" required>                
            </p>            
            <p>
                <label for="marca"> Marca: </label>
                <input type="text" name="marca" size="30" maxlength="30" id="marca">                
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="preco"> Preço: </label>
               <input type="text" name="preco" id="preco" pattern="[0-9]{1,9}\,[0-9]{1,2}$">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Salvar"> 
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

Vi numa das imagens que existe um outro erro sobre o `in` não conseguir ser resolvido pelo `String.trim()` por estar null. Acho que pode ser outro problema

Voltando um passo atrás, para o build: Você tem o Maven instalado? Poderia informar que erro ocorre ao rodar o comando `mvn clean install`?

Eu particularmente não gosto de utilizar deploys incrementais.
Executo o comando de build acima e arrasto o `.war` para a pasta de deployments, e só aí ligo server